# Optimal memory configuration on Dell R610 - 4 x 4GB and 2 x 8GB?

Tags: memory, hardware

I'm trying to install memory into a Dell R610 server, and am honestly at wit's end.

The DIMMS I have are:

- 4 x 4GB DDR3
- 2 x 8GB DDR3

I tried putting in the 4 x 4GB sticks in A1, A2, B1, B2 and the 2 x 8GB sticks in A3, B3 - but it complained:

```
The following DIMMS should match in size and geometry: DIMM A1, A2 & A3
```

I then tried putting in the 4 x 4GB sticks all on one CPU - A1, A2, A3 and A4. With the 2 x 8GB sticks on B1, B2.

However, it then complained about:

```
The memory configuration is not optimal.

CPU 1
A1:  DIMM A
A4:
A2: DIMM A
A5:
A3: DIMM 
A6:

DIMM configuration on each CPU should match.
```

I tried to follow the guide at http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-pedge-installing-upgrading-memory-11g.pdf, but couldn't seem to get it optimal.

Does anybody know what configuration I should be using?

Comment: AFAIK,there is simply no way to get the system to be happy with 6 sticks.  You need 2, 4 or 8.  You could probably get rid of a pair 4GB sticks, and have 2x4GB, and 2 8GB.  Or the other option is to buy another pair of 8GB sticks.  Not adding this as an 'answer', since I don't have the refs/manuals handy, just going of what I vaguely remember.

Answer (score 1):

The 610 has got three RAM channels, so A1, A2, A3 should have the same module size & type, and B1, B2, B3 should have the same module size & type.

Single CPU:

With 4 + 2 modules, there's no optimal layout.

The best solution is to replace one of the 4 GB DIMMs with a 8 GB DIMM, so you get two matching triplets.

Dual CPUs:

Plug 8 + 4 + 4 GB into each CPU's sockets, one DIMM per channel.

Comment: I tried this last night - 8GB sticks in A1, and B1, and then the 4GB sticks in A2, A3, B2, B3.

Unfortunately, it still gave me an error about non-optimal configuration.

https://i.imgur.com/eQZO6RG.jpg

Comment: Reread the answer - A/B is the DIMM number while 1/2/3 is the channel. Without buying another 8 GB stick, put 8GB in A1/A2 and the 4GB in B1/B2/B3. The last 4GB is spare. If you buy another (matching) 8GB stick put it in A3.